# Adding Json data as a source for dojogrid

Tags: javascript, json, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have a class in which i have a method name method() returning a String in the form of JSON string. The output is ::

```
[{"ID":1,"Names":"Shantanu"},{"ID":2,"Names":"Mayur"},{"ID":3,"Names":"Rohit"},{"ID":4,"Names":"Jasdeep"},{"ID":5,"Names":"Rakesh"}]
```

Now this in the form of data that i want to Populate for Datagrid using Dojo. And in My jsp page i am using it as follows ::

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="MyPackage.PopulateTextbox" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
@import "http://localhost:8080/2_8_2012/js/dojo/resources/dojo.css";

@import "http://localhost:8080/2_8_2012/js/dijit/themes/nihilo/nihilo.css";
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.4/dojo/dojo.xd.js" djConfig="isDebug: false, parseOnLoad: true"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript">

dojo.require("dojox.grid.DataGrid");
dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore");
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var temp1;
$(document).ready(function() {

PopulateTextbox obj = new PopulateTextbox();
temp1 = obj.method();
});
out.println(temp1);
var storedata={
        identifier:"table1",
        label:"name",
        items: temp1
}
var gridStructure =[{
cells:[
            [
                  { field: "ID",
                        name: "ID_Emp",
                        width: "40%", styles: 'text-align: right;'
                  },
                  {
                      field: "Names",
                      name: "Name",
                      width: "40%", styles: 'text-align: right;'
                  }

            ]
      ]
}];

</script>

<title>Dojo Data</title>
</head>
<body class=nihilo>
<div style="width: 400px; height: 300px;">
  <div data-dojo-type="dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore" data-dojo-id="countryStoreForGrid" data-dojo-props="data:storeData"></div>
  <div id="grid"
    data-dojo-type="dojox.grid.DataGrid"
    data-dojo-props="store:countryStoreForGrid,
    structure:'gridStructure',
    queryOptions:{deep:true},
    query:{},
    rowsPerPage:40">
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

What am i doing is as the page loads i am making an object of my PopulateTextbox class and calling the method which is returning a JSON string. And i am passing that string under ITEMS: as my data for Grid. Is it the right way of doin this ? can i call a method like this in javascript? If not, please suggest me the right way . When i run run this page i am getting an error ::

```
Webpage error details

Message: Expected ';'
Line: 25
Char: 17
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:8080/2_8_2012/DisplayData.jsp
```

Its the same line where i am writing

PopulateTextbox obj = new PopulateTextbox();

Code for PopulateTextbox.java

```
package MyPackage;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import net.sf.json.JSONArray;
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class PopulateTextbox {

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
    String temp1;

    String temp;
    List <String>rowValues = new ArrayList<String>();
    List <Integer>rowValues1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    String[] contactListNames;
    Connection con=null;
    Statement st=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;


    public String method(){


        try{


        String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
        Class.forName(driver);

        String db = "jdbc:odbc:Practice_Database";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(db,"","");

        st = con.createStatement();
        String sql = "SELECT Emp_Name,ID FROM EmployeeSearch";
        rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

        while(rs.next()){
            obj.put("ID", rs.getInt("ID"));
            obj.put("Names",rs.getString("Emp_Name"));
            arr.add(obj);
            //obj.add("Name", rs.getString("Emp_Name"));
            //rowValues1.add(rs.getInt("ID"));
            //rowValues.add(rs.getString("Emp_Name"));
            //obj.accumulate("Names",rs.getString("Emp_Name"));
        }
        //obj.accumulate("ID",rowValues1);

        //obj.accumulate("Names",rowValues);
        temp1 = arr.toString();
        System.out.println(temp1);
        contactListNames = (String[]) rowValues.toArray(new String[rowValues.size()]);
        temp = gson.toJson(contactListNames);




    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
    /*finally{
        try {
                if(con!=null)con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        try {
            if(rs!=null)rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }try {
            if(st!=null)st.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }*/
        return temp1;

    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        PopulateTextbox obj = new PopulateTextbox();
        String temp1= obj.method();


    }
}
```

Please help. thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Your PopulateTextBox is a java class but you seem to be referencing it in javascript code.

You can use JSP scriptlet to execute Java code in JSP

first, declare the string in the JSP declaration:

```
<%!
  String javaStr=null;
%>
```

Then, invoke your java function that populates the string:

```
<%

PopulateTextbox obj = new PopulateTextbox();
String javaStr = obj.method();

%>
```

Then, modify your javascript as follows:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var temp1;
$(document).ready(function() {

temp1 =<%= javaStr %>
});
```

remove the "out.println(temp1);" line from your javascript code

You can do a console.log(temp1) to view the data in firebug console, or alert(temp1) to ensure the data JSON is in the temp1 javascript variable